# Scope hierarchy issues after upgrading to Angular 1.2.1

Tags: angularjs

We recently upgraded to Angular 1.2.1 and are experiencing some issues with ng-include.

Here's a simplified example that shows our usage in Angular 1.1.1:
http://jsfiddle.net/Dq57j/1/

And here's another fiddle with Angular 1.2.1 with a workaround to our problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/78FJJ/4/

--HTML snip below--

```
   <div ng-controller="RootCtrl" id="a">
      Hello, {{name}}!

      <!-- does not work in Angular 1.2.1 -->
      <!--div ng-controller="TemplateCtrl" id="b"
           ng-include src="'template.html'">
      </div-->

      <!-- workaround -->
      <div ng-controller="TemplateCtrl" id="b">
          <div ng-include src="'template.html'">
          </div>  
   </div>
```

If you **comment out** the workaround and run the original code, this example will not work as expected, i.e. it outputs "Template saying:". It seems as though the template cannot read the scope initialized by TemplateCtrl.

If you investigate the issue further outside of jsfiddle and closely observe the scopes generated (e.g. using Batarang) you will see that the following scope hierarchy is generated (where the scope names reflect the id of the corresponding div):

a
|_ c
    |_ b

To me this seems really strange. How can Angular twist the scope hierarchy which according to me should be *a->b->c*? Note that the reason this example works in v.1.1.1 is that the hierarchy is *a->b->c* in that version of Angular.

Can anyone explain this and exactly what got changed between the two version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There have been a breaking change in version 1.2.0-rc3 impacting the way transclusion works, and the way transcluded / isolated scopes could communicate when on the same element.

So yes, now the ng-controller and the ng-include ( which is transclude : element ) on the same element will no longer share scope. This is the expected behaviour.

"Why" explication would be over complicated but yes, this is how it works now. Your "workaround" is the correct way to do that you want to do now.

EDIT : it's not 1.2.0-rc3, it's the final 1.2.0 : from changelog:

due to [909cabd3](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/909cabd36d779598763cc358979ecd85bb40d4d7), Directives without isolate scope do not get the isolate scope from an isolate directive on the same element. If your code depends on this behavior (non-isolate directive needs to access state from within the isolate scope), change the isolate directive to use scope locals to pass these explicitly.